# How to use index with Knex.js and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization, knex.js

I created an index for a column with Knex.js, but I can't find any way to use it.

```
knex('my_table')
.select('*')
.where('my_table.status', '2')
```

The index name is: **my_table_stats_idx**

I could do it with kex.raw() like:

```
FROM my_table USE INDEX(my_table_stats_idx)
```

But I had to use the a complex query building that didn’t fit with **raw()**

Is there a way to do that with Knex?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you don't tell the database which index it should use. All you do is *describe* the result you  want: the database makes the decision on *how* to process your statement. For this, the query planner takes in account various information, including, of course, available indexes. If it estimates that a plan that uses the index is optimal, the index is used - else it is not.

You don't tell what the definition of your index is. For your query, the optimal index probably is a single-column index on `my_table(status)`.

Finally: in most databases, there are ways to suggest the database to use a given index, through hints. These are useful in edge cases where the query planner is not able to figure out things by itself. Your query clearly is not complex enough to qualify as such case.

Comment: So, I don't need to do nothing more?! Ok, I'll try that. Just to explain, that's not my real query. The real one has 30 or more lines. But thanks for your answer!

Comment: @dm707: no, you don't need to do anything more. Just make sure that [the statistics of the table are up to date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-statistics.html), so MySQL has all the information it needs to build the best query plan.

Answer (score 0):

You need knex.raw in the from clause

```
   knex
  .select('*')
   .where('my_table.status', '2')
  .from(knex.raw('my_table  FORCE INDEX(my_table_stats_idx)'))
```

Comment: I tried that, but to use knex like that it's deprecated. We should use like: knex('my_table'). But thanks

Comment: that syntax is in the last version http://knexjs.org/

Comment: I think they didn’t update the entire documentation. It's not shown on the sidebar, but it's still present on almost all code examples. But I receive the deprecated message when I use it.